# Command in Xcode for tar.gz?

Tags: xcode, command, tar

I am trying to make a simple command line tool in Xcode, that will allow me to make a tar.gz out of a specific folder. I want to see if i can make a program to autorun the command line, instead of typing it in every time i want to make a tar.gz out of something.

> int main (int argc, const char *
>   argv[]) {
>
> // insert code here...
>
> tar czvf SealTeamSix.tar.gz /Users/mdonovan14/Blah
>
> return 0;
>   }

I understand that i am not setting this up right. How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using Automator to create a script that runs that snippet of shell script. Do the following:

1. Launch Automator.
2. Choose the Application template.
3. Drag a Run Shell Script action into the work flow.
4. Paste your script into text field.
5. Save your new application, giving it a useful name.
6. Switch to the Finder and run your app.
7. Profit!

As it is, you're trying to mix shell scripting into a C program. You can certainly run shell scripts from C using the system() function, but using Automator here as described above is a much friendlier process.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add a text field for input, where i can say what file i want to make a tar.gz of? I just started programming, so im sorry if i have no idea what im talking about

Comment: Better, the Run Shell Script action takes a list of files as input. So you can set it up to use those files in your script. You'll need to take a look at [the documentation](http://tinyurl.com/4xpvuby) to get it working right, but once you get the hang of Automator it'll become a very powerful tool that takes a lot of pain out of creating scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which lets you run command-line programs